# fullcalendar multi day event is not displaying

Tags: yii

I am using full calendar in *yii*,but full calendar is not       showing any events when i set the events for more than one day(multi day events) but it will display the event when i set it only for one day ,actually i want to display attendance of a student for a month .(just go through my controller if a student is absent it will show a color and another for present,it is not showing any output when i set one day is present and another day is absent,another day is present in a month,but if i set one case ie absent/present/leave only for a day in a month it will show the output.

```
                     <?php $this->widget('ext.Efullcalendar.EFullCalendar',                       array(
                     'themeCssFile'=>'cupertino/theme.css',
                     'htmlOptions'=>array(
    // you can scale it down as well, try 80%
    //'onload'=>'.fullCalendar( "gotoDate", "12-12-2016" )'

                                         ),
        'options'=>array(
            'header'=>array(
                  'left'=>'prev,next,today',
                  'center'=>'title',
                  'right'=>'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
                            ),
                  'events'=>$events // URL to get event
                         )));
      ?>


  $.ajax({
       success: function(events){
                    $('#yw0').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                    $('#yw0').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
                },
       type: 'get',
       url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('renderattendance');?>',
       cache: false,
       data: {
          year: year,
          month: month,
       },
       dataType: 'json',
    });







{
            $month=$_GET['month'];
            $year=$_GET['year'];

        }  $noofdays=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year);
    $student_model=$this->loadModel();  
    $student_id=$student_model->id;
    $events=array();
    $att_array=Attendance::getParentAttendanceMonth($student_id,$month,$year);
    //$att_array[]=array('date'=>'2016-09-01','f'=>'present');
    //$att_array[]=array('date'=>'2016-09-02','f'=>'absent');//print_r($att_array);die;
    foreach($att_array as $i=>$att)
    {
            switch($att->present)
            {
                case Attendance::ABSENT:
                {
                    $events[$i]['title']='absent';
                    $events[$i]['start']=$att['date'];
                    $events[$i]['color']='#FA0000';
                    break;
                }
                case Attendance::PRESENT:
                {
                    $events[$i]['title']='present';
                    $events[$i]['start']=$att['date'];
                    $events[$i]['color']='#43E8A6';
                    break;
                }
                case Attendance::LEAVE:
                {
                    $events[$i]['title']='leave';
                    $events[$i]['start']=$att['date'];
                    $events[$i]['color']='#949fef';
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    $events[$i]['title']='n-a';
                    $events[$i]['start']=$att['date'];
                    $events[$i]['color']='#999999';
                    break;
                }
            }
        echo CJSON::encode($events);
    }

}
```

Comment: please explain more with your code of controller and view fiile.

Comment: after ajax i have given my action renderattendance